# How can I list all files from a web server's directory with their name, mime type, upload date etc.?

Tags: php, list, types, directory, upload

I am trying to make a file hosting project with `php`. I already did the upload part, and all of the uploaded files go to a specific directory on the server.

Now, I need to display all of the files in that directory to the user on one page, with their name, mime type, upload date, etc.

Do you know how I can do this?

I can already list all the files from a directory (example below), but I have no idea how to get more info (mime type, upload date), etc.

```
$files = scandir( "uploadedfiles" );
        foreach( $files as $file ){
           echo $file . "<br>";
        }
```